(BigQuery) Unwanted Field is Created When Trying to Create Dynamic Fields in ARRAY_STRUCT
I'm trying to create a key feature data mart using nested structs in BigQuery. Everything is working fine except that an unwanted random field is being created in the inner ARRAY_STRUCT (e.d struct) while creating the final CTE "fin_table."
It seems that the number of columns being created exceeds the number specified in the struct_fields variable for dynamic fields, which is denoted by %s.↳
The random field has a random integer at the end of the field name, such as "_field_9." Because of this field, I can't append new data.
Please let me know how to get rid of this random field.
Thanks!
current result table schema is like below (problematic field is _field_9)
{'Event_Date': 'DATE',
'Airbridge_Device_ID': 'STRING',
…
…
'e': {'type': 'RECORD',
'mode': 'REPEATED',
'fields': {'Label': 'STRING',
'Action': 'STRING',
'Event_Value_Sum': 'FLOAT',
'Event_Count': 'INTEGER',
'u': {'type': 'RECORD',
'mode': 'REPEATED',
'fields': {'User_ID': 'STRING'}},
'd': {'type': 'RECORD',
'mode': 'REPEATED',
'fields': {'Timestamp': 'STRING',
'Label': 'STRING',
'Action': 'STRING',
'Value': 'FLOAT',
'tester': 'STRING',
'products_struct_alias': {'type': 'RECORD',
'mode': 'REPEATED',
'fields': {'name': 'STRING', 'price': 'STRING', 'position': 'STRING'}},
'productID': 'STRING',
'price': 'STRING',
'name': 'STRING',
'_field_9': 'STRING',
'transactionID': 'STRING',
}}}}
query is like below

-- Declare UDF, JSON parsing
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION extract_key_value(json STRING, key STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var obj = JSON.parse(json);
  return obj[key] || null;
""";

-- Declare UDF, check key existence
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION has_key(json STRING, key STRING)
RETURNS BOOL
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var obj = JSON.parse(json);
  return obj.hasOwnProperty(key);
""";

-- BEGIN ~ END
BEGIN

  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #
  -- Declare variables, must be used the same number of times
  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #   
  DECLARE key_list STRING DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE struct_fields STRING DEFAULT '';

  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #
  -- Generate key list for dynamic pivot query
  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #   
  SET key_list = (
    WITH json_table AS (
        SELECT 
            Event_Date, Event_Datetime, 
            Airbridge_Device_ID, Airbridge_Device_ID_Type, User_ID,
            Campaign_ID, Ad_Group_ID, Ad_Creative_ID, Term_ID,
            Device_Model, Device_Type, Platform, Client_IP_Country_Code, Client_IP_Subdivision, Client_IP_City, 
            Is_Re_engagement, Is_First_Event_per_User_ID, Is_First_Event_per_Device_ID,
            Is_First_Target_Event_per_Device, Target_Event_Timestamp, Target_Event_Category,
            Event_Category, Event_Label, Event_Action, Event_Value,
            CASE 
                WHEN Custom_Event_Properties = '{}' THEN '{"tester": "true"}'
                ELSE Custom_Event_Properties
            END AS Custom_Event_Properties,
            Semantic_Event_Properties
        FROM 
            `airbridge_lake.app_2024`
        WHERE
            Event_Date = '2024-07-13'
    ),

    keys_extracted AS (
      SELECT
        REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Semantic_Event_Properties, r'"([^"]+)":') AS semantic_keys,
        REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Custom_Event_Properties, r'"([^"]+)":') AS custom_keys
      FROM
        json_table
    ),

    distinct_keys AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT key
      FROM keys_extracted,
      UNNEST(semantic_keys) AS key
      WHERE key NOT IN ('products') -- Add potential nested key
      UNION DISTINCT
      SELECT DISTINCT key
      FROM keys_extracted,
      UNNEST(custom_keys) AS key
    )

    SELECT
      CONCAT('("', STRING_AGG(key, '", "'), '")') AS keys
    FROM distinct_keys
  );

  -- Set the dynamic struct fields for the final SELECT
  SET struct_fields = (
    WITH json_table AS (
        SELECT 
            Event_Date, Event_Datetime,
            Airbridge_Device_ID, Airbridge_Device_ID_Type, User_ID,
            Campaign_ID, Ad_Group_ID, Ad_Creative_ID, Term_ID,
            Device_Model, Device_Type, Platform, Client_IP_Country_Code, Client_IP_Subdivision, Client_IP_City, 
            Is_Re_engagement, Is_First_Event_per_User_ID, Is_First_Event_per_Device_ID,
            Is_First_Target_Event_per_Device, Target_Event_Timestamp, Target_Event_Category,
            Event_Category, Event_Label, Event_Action, Event_Value,
            CASE 
                WHEN Custom_Event_Properties = '{}' THEN '{"tester": "true"}'
                ELSE Custom_Event_Properties
            END AS Custom_Event_Properties,
            Semantic_Event_Properties
        FROM 
            `airbridge_lake.app_2024`
        WHERE
            Event_Date = '2024-07-13'
    ),

    keys_extracted AS (
      SELECT
        REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Semantic_Event_Properties, r'"([^"]+)":') AS semantic_keys,
        REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Custom_Event_Properties, r'"([^"]+)":') AS custom_keys
      FROM
        json_table
    ),

    distinct_keys AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT key
      FROM keys_extracted,
      UNNEST(semantic_keys) AS key
      WHERE key NOT IN ('products') -- Add potential nested key
      UNION DISTINCT
      SELECT DISTINCT key
      FROM keys_extracted,
      UNNEST(custom_keys) AS key
    )

    SELECT
      STRING_AGG(CONCAT('IFNULL(', key, ', NULL) AS ', key), ', ') AS keys
    FROM distinct_keys
  );

  -- Check if key_list or struct_fields are NULL
  IF key_list IS NULL THEN
    SET key_list = '("dummy_key")';
  END IF;
  
  IF struct_fields IS NULL THEN
    SET struct_fields = 'IFNULL(dummy_key, NULL) AS dummy_key';
  END IF;

  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #
  -- Execute dynamic pivot query
  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #   
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  WITH json_table AS (
      SELECT 
        Event_Date, Event_Datetime, 
        Airbridge_Device_ID, Airbridge_Device_ID_Type, User_ID,
        Campaign_ID, Ad_Group_ID, Ad_Creative_ID, Term_ID,
        Device_Model, Device_Type, Platform, Client_IP_Country_Code, Client_IP_Subdivision, Client_IP_City, 
        Is_Re_engagement, Is_First_Event_per_User_ID, Is_First_Event_per_Device_ID,
        Is_First_Target_Event_per_Device, Target_Event_Timestamp, Target_Event_Category,
        Event_Category, Event_Label, Event_Action, Event_Value,
        CASE 
            WHEN Custom_Event_Properties = '{}' THEN '{"tester": "true"}'
            ELSE Custom_Event_Properties
        END AS Custom_Event_Properties,
        Semantic_Event_Properties
    FROM `airbridge_lake.app_2024`
    WHERE Event_Date = '2024-07-13'
  ),

  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #
  -- Extract and handle duplicate JSON keys
  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #    

  keys_extracted AS (
    SELECT
      *,
      REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Semantic_Event_Properties, r'"([^"]+)":') AS semantic_keys,
      REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Custom_Event_Properties, r'"([^"]+)":') AS custom_keys
    FROM
      json_table
  ),

  filtered_keys AS (
    SELECT
      *,
      ARRAY(
        SELECT key FROM UNNEST(semantic_keys) AS key
        WHERE key NOT IN ('products')
        UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT key FROM UNNEST(custom_keys) AS key
      ) AS filtered_keys
    FROM
      keys_extracted
  ),

  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #
  -- Create key table
  -- 1. Use filtered_keys array to create key column
  -- 2. Use UDF to parse JSON
  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #    

  unnested_semantic_keys AS (
    SELECT
        Event_Date, Event_Datetime, 
        Airbridge_Device_ID, Airbridge_Device_ID_Type, User_ID,
        Campaign_ID, Ad_Group_ID, Ad_Creative_ID, Term_ID,
        Device_Model, Device_Type, Platform, Client_IP_Country_Code, Client_IP_Subdivision, Client_IP_City, 
        Is_Re_engagement, Is_First_Event_per_User_ID, Is_First_Event_per_Device_ID,
        Is_First_Target_Event_per_Device, Target_Event_Timestamp, Target_Event_Category,
        Event_Category, Event_Label, Event_Action, Event_Value,
        Semantic_Event_Properties, Custom_Event_Properties,
        key,
        extract_key_value(Semantic_Event_Properties, key) AS value
    FROM
      filtered_keys,
      UNNEST(filtered_keys.filtered_keys) AS key
  ),

  unnested_custom_keys AS (
    SELECT
        Event_Date, Event_Datetime,
        Airbridge_Device_ID, Airbridge_Device_ID_Type, User_ID,
        Campaign_ID, Ad_Group_ID, Ad_Creative_ID, Term_ID,
        Device_Model, Device_Type, Platform, Client_IP_Country_Code, Client_IP_Subdivision, Client_IP_City, 
        Is_Re_engagement, Is_First_Event_per_User_ID, Is_First_Event_per_Device_ID,
        Is_First_Target_Event_per_Device, Target_Event_Timestamp, Target_Event_Category,
        Event_Category, Event_Label, Event_Action, Event_Value,
        Semantic_Event_Properties, Custom_Event_Properties,
        key,
        extract_key_value(Custom_Event_Properties, key) AS value
    FROM
      filtered_keys,
      UNNEST(filtered_keys.filtered_keys) AS key
  ),

  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #
  -- Concatenate key tables
  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #  

  combined_keys AS (
    SELECT
        Event_Date, Event_Datetime, 
        Airbridge_Device_ID, Airbridge_Device_ID_Type, User_ID,
        Campaign_ID, Ad_Group_ID, Ad_Creative_ID, Term_ID,
        Device_Model, Device_Type, Platform, Client_IP_Country_Code, Client_IP_Subdivision, Client_IP_City, 
        Is_Re_engagement, Is_First_Event_per_User_ID, Is_First_Event_per_Device_ID,
        Is_First_Target_Event_per_Device, Target_Event_Timestamp, Target_Event_Category,
        Event_Category, Event_Label, Event_Action, Event_Value,
        Semantic_Event_Properties, Custom_Event_Properties,
        key,
        extract_key_value(Semantic_Event_Properties, key) AS value
    FROM
        unnested_semantic_keys
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Event_Date, Event_Datetime, 
        Airbridge_Device_ID, Airbridge_Device_ID_Type, User_ID,
        Campaign_ID, Ad_Group_ID, Ad_Creative_ID, Term_ID,
        Device_Model, Device_Type, Platform, Client_IP_Country_Code, Client_IP_Subdivision, Client_IP_City, 
        Is_Re_engagement, Is_First_Event_per_User_ID, Is_First_Event_per_Device_ID,
        Is_First_Target_Event_per_Device, Target_Event_Timestamp, Target_Event_Category,
        Event_Category, Event_Label, Event_Action, Event_Value,
        Semantic_Event_Properties, Custom_Event_Properties,
        key,
        extract_key_value(Custom_Event_Properties, key) AS value
    FROM
        unnested_custom_keys
  ),

  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #
  -- Create Products Nested JSON table
  -- 1. Handle 2-level JSON, null values separately (branch)
  -- 2. Merge after creation
  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #  

  product_keys_extracted AS (
    SELECT
      Event_Date, Event_Datetime, Airbridge_Device_ID, Event_Category, Event_Label, Event_Action, Event_Value,
      IFNULL(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(Semantic_Event_Properties, '$.products'), []) AS products
    FROM
      json_table
  ),

  products_unnested AS (
    SELECT
      Event_Date, Event_Datetime, Airbridge_Device_ID, Event_Category, Event_Label, Event_Action, Event_Value,
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(product, '$.name') AS name,
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(product, '$.price') AS price,
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(product, '$.position') AS position
    FROM
      product_keys_extracted,
      UNNEST(products) AS product
  ),

  products_struct AS (
    SELECT
      Event_Date, Event_Datetime, Airbridge_Device_ID, Event_Category, Event_Label, Event_Action, Event_Value,
      ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(name as name, price as price, position as position)) AS products_struct
    FROM products_unnested
    GROUP BY Event_Date, Event_Datetime, Airbridge_Device_ID, Event_Category, Event_Label, Event_Action, Event_Value
  ),

  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #
  -- Create pivot table
  -- 1. Select table with key, value columns parsed from Semantic, Custom JSON
  -- 2. Pivot key-value using declared variables.
  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #  

  pivot_table AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM combined_keys
    PIVOT (
      ANY_VALUE(value) FOR key IN %s
    )
  ),

  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #
  -- Create merged table
  -- 1. Select pivot table parsed from Semantic, Custom JSON
  -- 2. Select table parsed and structured from Product Nested JSON in Semantic
  -- 3. Merge based on key values
  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #

  merged_table AS (
    SELECT
        table_1.Event_Date, table_1.Event_Datetime, 
        table_1.Airbridge_Device_ID, table_1.Airbridge_Device_ID_Type, table_1.User_ID,
        table_1.Campaign_ID, table_1.Ad_Group_ID, table_1.Ad_Creative_ID, table_1.Term_ID,
        table_1.Device_Model, table_1.Device_Type, table_1.Platform, table_1.Client_IP_Country_Code, table_1.Client_IP_Subdivision, table_1.Client_IP_City, 
        table_1.Is_Re_engagement, table_1.Is_First_Event_per_User_ID, table_1.Is_First_Event_per_Device_ID,
        table_1.Is_First_Target_Event_per_Device, table_1.Target_Event_Timestamp, table_1.Target_Event_Category,
        table_1.Event_Category, table_1.Event_Label, table_1.Event_Action, table_1.Event_Value,
        table_1.Semantic_Event_Properties, table_1.Custom_Event_Properties,
        table_2.products_struct AS products_str,
        table_1.* EXCEPT (
          Event_Date, Event_Datetime, 
          Airbridge_Device_ID, Airbridge_Device_ID_Type, User_ID,
          Campaign_ID, Ad_Group_ID, Ad_Creative_ID, Term_ID,
          Device_Model, Device_Type, Platform, Client_IP_Country_Code, Client_IP_Subdivision, Client_IP_City, 
          Is_Re_engagement, Is_First_Event_per_User_ID, Is_First_Event_per_Device_ID,
          Is_First_Target_Event_per_Device, Target_Event_Timestamp, Target_Event_Category,
          Event_Category, Event_Label, Event_Action, Event_Value, Semantic_Event_Properties, Custom_Event_Properties
        ),
        table_2.* EXCEPT (
          Event_Date, Event_Datetime, Airbridge_Device_ID, Event_Category, Event_Label, Event_Action, Event_Value
        )
    FROM
      pivot_table as table_1
    LEFT JOIN 
      products_struct as table_2
      ON table_1.Event_Date = table_2.Event_Date AND 
       table_1.Event_Datetime = table_2.Event_Datetime AND 
       table_1.Airbridge_Device_ID = table_2.Airbridge_Device_ID AND
       table_1.Event_Category = table_2.Event_Category AND
       table_1.Event_Label = table_2.Event_Label AND
       table_1.Event_Action = table_2.Event_Action AND
       table_1.Event_Value = table_2.Event_Value
  ),

  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #
  -- Order merged table (no significant functionality)
  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #

  order_table AS (
    SELECT 
      Event_Date, Airbridge_Device_ID, Airbridge_Device_ID_Type, 
      Device_Model, Device_Type, Platform, Client_IP_Country_Code, Client_IP_Subdivision, Client_IP_City, 
      User_ID, 
      Campaign_ID, Ad_Group_ID, Ad_Creative_ID, Term_ID,
      Is_Re_engagement, Is_First_Event_per_User_ID, Is_First_Event_per_Device_ID,
      Is_First_Target_Event_per_Device, Target_Event_Timestamp, Target_Event_Category,
      Event_Datetime, Event_Category, Event_Label, Event_Action, Event_Value,
      merged_table.* EXCEPT (
        Event_Date, Airbridge_Device_ID, Airbridge_Device_ID_Type, 
        Device_Model, Device_Type, Platform, Client_IP_Country_Code, Client_IP_Subdivision, Client_IP_City, 
        User_ID, Campaign_ID, Ad_Group_ID, Ad_Creative_ID, Term_ID,
        Is_Re_engagement, Is_First_Event_per_User_ID, Is_First_Event_per_Device_ID,
        Is_First_Target_Event_per_Device, Target_Event_Timestamp, Target_Event_Category,
        Event_Datetime, Event_Category, Event_Label, Event_Action, Event_Value
      )
    FROM merged_table
  ),

  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #
  -- Final table
  -- 1. Create 2-level struct for semantic and custom columns
  -- 2. Group by Event Action, Event Label by Date and Timestamp
  -- 3. Create Value and Count features for each event after 2-level group by
  -- 4. Create 1:N struct for User_ID
  -- 5. Create structs for device info, campaign info, etc.
  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------- #

  fin_table AS(
    SELECT 
      Event_Date, Airbridge_Device_ID, Airbridge_Device_ID_Type,
      -- Create struct for other information --
      STRUCT(
        min(Device_Model) as Device_Model ,min(Device_Type) as Device_Type ,min(Platform) as Platform ,min(Client_IP_Country_Code) as Client_IP_Country_Code ,min(Client_IP_Subdivision) as Client_IP_Subdivision ,min(Client_IP_City) as Client_IP_City
        ,min(Campaign_ID) as Campaign_ID ,min(Ad_Group_ID) as Ad_Group_ID ,min(Ad_Creative_ID) as Ad_Creative_ID ,min(Term_ID) as Term_ID
        ,min(Is_Re_engagement) as Is_Re_engagement, min(Is_First_Event_per_User_ID) as Is_First_Event_per_User_ID, min(Is_First_Event_per_Device_ID) as Is_First_Event_per_Device_ID
        ,min(Is_First_Target_Event_per_Device) as Is_First_Target_Event_per_Device
        ,min(Target_Event_Timestamp) as Target_Event_Timestamp, min(Target_Event_Category) as Target_Event_Category
      ) AS i,
      Event_Category,SUM(Event_Value_Sum) as Event_Value_Total, SUM(Event_Count) as Event_Count_Total,
      -- Create struct for event details. This is the outer struct of the 2-level struct --
      ARRAY_AGG(
        STRUCT(
          Event_Label as Label, Event_Action as Action, Event_Value_Sum as Event_Value_Sum, Event_Count, u as u, d as d
        )
      ) as e
    FROM(
      -- Start subquery --
      SELECT 
          Event_Date, Airbridge_Device_ID, Airbridge_Device_ID_Type,
          -- Create struct for User ID --
          ARRAY_AGG(
            STRUCT(
              User_ID as User_ID
            )
          ) as u,
          
          Event_Category, Event_Label, Event_Action, SUM(Event_Value) AS Event_Value_Sum, COUNT(*) AS Event_Count,
          min(Device_Model) as Device_Model ,min(Device_Type) as Device_Type ,min(Platform) as Platform ,min(Client_IP_Country_Code) as Client_IP_Country_Code ,min(Client_IP_Subdivision) as Client_IP_Subdivision ,min(Client_IP_City) as Client_IP_City
          ,min(Campaign_ID) as Campaign_ID ,min(Ad_Group_ID) as Ad_Group_ID ,min(Ad_Creative_ID) as Ad_Creative_ID ,min(Term_ID) as Term_ID
          ,min(Is_Re_engagement) as Is_Re_engagement, min(Is_First_Event_per_User_ID) as Is_First_Event_per_User_ID, min(Is_First_Event_per_Device_ID) as Is_First_Event_per_Device_ID
          ,min(Is_First_Target_Event_per_Device) as Is_First_Target_Event_per_Device
          ,min(Target_Event_Timestamp) as Target_Event_Timestamp, min(Target_Event_Category) as Target_Event_Category,

          -- Create struct for event details. This is the inner struct of the 2-level struct --
          ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT( 
            Event_Datetime as Timestamp ,Event_Label as Label, Event_Action as Action, Event_Value as Value, %s, products_str
          )) AS d
      FROM order_table
      GROUP BY Event_Date, Airbridge_Device_ID, Airbridge_Device_ID_Type, Event_Category, Event_Label, Event_Action
    ) AS inn
    GROUP BY Event_Date, Airbridge_Device_ID, Airbridge_Device_ID_Type, Event_Category
  )
  
  select * from fin_table
  
  -- Use declared variables --
  """, key_list, struct_fields); 
END;



can't figure out the problems

So run each of those (sub) select statements in turn until you find the one causing the issue. If you then can’t resolve the issue update your question with just the code necessary to reproduce it

@NickW
thankyou. problem only shows up at ARRAY_AGG in fin_table
ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(
Event_Datetime as Timestamp ,Event_Label as Label, Event_Action as Action, Event_Value as Value, %s, products_str
)) AS d code

Ok - so maybe update your question to get rid of all the irrelevant code and instead produce a minimal reproducible example that just has a source table with data, the above code in the form of an executable SQL statement and the result it gives?

@NickW OK I'll try. But the fin_table CTE needs variables which are declared and treated above. Is it OK get rid off that parts?

If it’s irrelevant to the actual issue you are facing then get rid of it. All you need is the simplest SQL statement possible that generates the unwanted column

@NickW OK thanks. It Would take times I think, when It finished I'll tag you. thks for help
